# How do I configure cmake to link to prebuilt shared libraries?

Tags: cmake

I have a project that includes a prebuilt version of opencv in a subdirectory. For example:

MyProject
* CMakeLists.txt
* src
* third_party
** CMakeLists.txt
** opencv
**** include
**** lib

I would like to link against the version of opencv located in the third_party directory. My question is, how do I inform CMake to link to the prebuilt dylib files in lib, and include the headers in the relevant opencv directory?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (myproject)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/lib)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_executable(myproject ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myproject opencv_calib3d opencv_contrib opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_features2d opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)
```

Comment: If you use `find_package(OpenCV)`, then `set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv)` before it. Alternatively you can use direct paths: `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/include)` and corresponded `link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/lib)` call. What is the problem with these standard commands?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have taken your suggestions and applied them (see ammended question description). Unfortunately I still get a linker error (ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)

Comment: Plesase, add linker's error message into your question. Do you have another OpenCV library, installed into default path? It looks strange that linker has found library files, but hasn't found symbols in it.

Comment: The error message is simply a symbols not found message, indicating that I am not linking to the library

Comment: "Symbol(s) not found" message indicates that all requested (in `target_link_libraries()`) **libraries are found**, but **none of them defines given symbol**. BTW, this error can be resulted from incorrect symbol name, used by the code.

Comment: My apologies, the error I actually get is `ld: library not found for -l<library_name>`

Comment: Does this library file exist under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/lib`? (BTW, what's a reason to hide actual name of the **free** library?? Knowing this name sometimes may help in resolving resason of the problem.)

Comment: No reason for hiding the name other than to avoid enumerating all of the libraries. One example is libflann.dylib. In this example my cmake file would contain: `link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/prebuilt/libs)
target_link_libraries(myproject flann)`. The error is `ld: library not found for -lflann`

Comment: How `flann` library is related with openCV?

Answer (score 8):

I've given your example a try with CMake 3.3.2 on OS X 10.11 having XCode 7.0.1.

Using the [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/link_directories.html) and [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html) approach suggested by @Tsyvarev seems to work without raising any linker warnings or errors (it finds the `.dylib` libraries I placed in the `third_party` directory).

Just a view hints, that hopefully could get you a start why it's not working on your Mac.

- With your code I get the following command line linker file (inside CMake's binary output directory):

  **CMakeFiles/myproject.dir/src/link.txt**

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    
  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk 
  -Wl,-search_paths_first 
  -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  
  CMakeFiles/myproject.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o myproject  
  -L[...CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR...]/third_party/opencv/lib  
  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc 
  -Wl,-rpath,[...CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR...]/third_party/opencv/lib
  ```
- You can try to give full library paths, because those are additionally checked by CMake itself and it gets more obvious what I link against. Here is a modified version of your example:

  **CMakeLists.txt**

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
  project (myproject)

  include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv/include)

  file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
  file(GLOB LIBRARIES "third_party/opencv/lib/*.dylib")
  message("LIBRARIES = ${LIBRARIES}")

  add_executable(myproject ${SOURCES})
  target_link_libraries(myproject ${LIBRARIES})
  ```

  With this CMake just adds fully qualified paths (relative to my binary output directory) into the linker file. The `-L` and `-l` options are gone and you get "lines" like:

  ```
  ../third_party/opencv/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib
  ```

**Additional Q/A References**

- [OpenCV installation on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671827/opencv-installation-on-mac-os-x)
- [How to use dylib file in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400478/how-to-use-dylib-file-in-application)
- [CMake link_directories from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153019/cmake-link-directories-from-library)
- [Force CMake to use the full library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165270/force-cmake-to-use-the-full-library-path)