# Add dylib to app file

Tags: macos, cmake, bundle, dylib

I am working on OSX application. This application uses dylib. I would like to ship that lib in the package so user does not need to have it.
How can I do that using cmake.

As well I would like to know how can I tell cmake to look for dylib or framework files in the custom location

Edit: I would like to add more information.
The lib I want to add is called libopenal.
Checking the package with otool I see:

```
/opt/local/lib/libopenal.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.15.1)
```

If I check my .app file in folder:

```
myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
```

I have libopenal.1.dylib. Would it work just changing the previous line to point to libopenal.1.dylib stored in my bundle or do I need to do something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure cmake to link to prebuilt shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980381/how-do-i-configure-cmake-to-link-to-prebuilt-shared-libraries)

Comment: In that comment it is not explained how to add the dylib file to the package

Comment: @RuLoViC What CMake generator type are you using and are you signing your app bundle?

Comment: @CraigScott Unix Makefiles